# predict_proba in new version of fasttext

Tags: python, fasttext

I have built a classifier which has 16 classes. I need the top three predicted classes. I used to use older versions of fasttext, and for getting the probabilities i used give

```
mymodel = fasttext.load_model("path to saved model")
mymodel.predict_proba(_mysentence, k= 3)
```

but when I am trying to use fasttext=0.9.1, it says the functionality doesnt exist.

```
AttributeError: '_FastText' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

how it is modified in newer version to get the top 3 labels?

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version of the fasttext (0.9.1), we can get from

```
mymodel = fasttext.load_model("path_to_saved_model.ftz")
mymodel.predict("_mysentence", k=3)
```

it will return some thing similar

```
(('__label__class10', '__label__class2', '__label__class16'), array([1.00001001e+00, 1.00116731e-05, 1.00000225e-05]))

# ((predicted_class,...),array([confidence_score, ...]))
```

The class predictions are sorted by it confidence and returns the top three when k=3